# Sync. SelectedIndex of two multiselect Listboxes

Tags: c#, listbox, multi-select

I'm strungling to sync. the selectedIndexs of two multi-select Listboxes.
With single-select enabled the code is just:

```
 private void libHT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        libMonth.SelectedIndex = libHT.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

But this doesn't work if multi-select is enabled. 
Can you help me? Do I have to use a for or foreach?

Thanks for your help.
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `SelectedIndices` property.

```
private void libHT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        libMonth.SelectedIndices.Clear();
        foreach (var index in libHT.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>())
        {
            libMonth.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
        }
}
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to loop over all the selections. Code like below can help you with that

```
private void libHT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    libMonth.SelectedIndices.Clear();
    foreach (int indx in libHT.SelectedIndices)
        libMonth.SelectedIndices.Add(indx);
}
```

Don't forget:

1. To hook the index changed event: `libHT.SelectedIndexChanged += libHT_SelectedIndexChanged;`
2. To set the selection mode correctly `libHT.SelectionMode = libMonth.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;`
3. To watch out for your programmatic selection, causing infinite recursion